# Jquery change button on click

Tags: jquery, class, button, click

I have a simple page which has four cards (Divs), each with a button. I've written some jquery in the hopes that when i click on the button i can change the class & text of the button... and toggle between the two states as i continue to click them.

My below code seems to work for the first button perfectly... but not any of the others.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#un_btn").click(function() {
                if ($(this).attr('class') == 'btn_s') {
                    $(this).html('Undo?');
                    $(this).removeClass('btn_s');
                    $(this).addClass('notsu');
                } else {
                    $(this).html('Mark as not suitable?');
                    $(this).removeClass('notsu');
                    $(this).addClass('btn_s');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <p>Card 1</p>
        <button class="btn_s" id="un_btn">Mark as not suitable?</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <p>Card 2</p>
        <button class="btn_s" id="un_btn">Mark as not suitable?</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <p>Card 3</p>
        <button class="btn_s" id="un_btn">Mark as not suitable?</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <p>Card 4</p>
        <button class="btn_s" id="un_btn">Mark as not suitable?</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i get the toggle to work on each button within each respective div (card)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **ID should be Unique** use class instead for similar elements.
2. Use `hasClass` to check if an element have some class instead of using `attr('class')`
3. The methods `addClass`, `removeClass` and `html` on same element can be chained.
4. Instead of using `addClass` and `removeClass`, `toggleClass` can be used with two classes.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5gk5hsta/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Bind click event on all the buttons inside .card
  $(".card button").click(function() {
    
    // Check if the clicked button has class `btn_s`
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn_s')) {
      $(this).html('Undo?').toggleClass('btn_s notsu');
    } else {
      $(this).html('Mark as not suitable?').toggleClass('notsu btn_s');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.notsu {
  color: red;
}
.btn_s {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p>Card 1</p>
  <button class="btn_s">Mark as not suitable?</button>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>Card 2</p>
  <button class="btn_s">Mark as not suitable?</button>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>Card 3</p>
  <button class="btn_s">Mark as not suitable?</button>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <p>Card 4</p>
  <button class="btn_s">Mark as not suitable?</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Click works fine for the rendered elements. Since you are adding the elements dynamically, you have to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this. 
It looks like you are adding this element dynamically, so you'll need to use a delegated event listener:

Modify your code

```
 $("#un_btn").click(function() {}); to 

 $(document).on('click', "your selector", function() { });
```

Selector may be class or Id. .btn_s or #un_btn

Answer (score 0):

You Are checking for the Id name instead of the Class in your jquery. You should really not have Id's the same, because it causes problems like this.

If you change the line:

```
$("#un_btn").click(function(){
```

with

```
$(".btn_s").click(function(){
```

This works fine.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2e6bp84/) is a JsFiddle of it working with this change